# How to use Intent in onChildClick()method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am copying down a piece of code in which whenever I clicked on a child item it should point me to the respective page!

```js
//CODE STARTS //
  public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int gp=groupPosition;
             if (gp == 0)
             {
                 switch(childPosition)
                 {
                 case 0 :
                 Intent   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://www.arsenal.com"));
                 }
                    
             } 
                  
                return false;
            }
// CODE ENDS //
```

So, if I click on the item at child position 0th then it should re direct me to Arsenal.com! It's not working though! It keeps me on the same page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `startActivity(intent);` to launch the browser activity.